# Важность Exit() в конце скрипта

Tags: php

Почему ,если переправлять пользователя важно применять exit()?

```
header('Location: http://smowhere.com');
exit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это важно, т.к. обычно перенаправление используется в случае невозможного/неавторизованного действия, т.е.

```
if (!$user->is_logged()) {
    header('Location: /login');
    exit; //иногда в фреймворках $app->finish();
}
echo "Hello {$user->name}!";
```

если у вас просто страница редиректа (зачем это может быть нужно мне неведомо), то естественно exit; необязателен.

Answer (score 2):

Для прекращения выполнения текущего скрипта. К примеру, у вас такой код:

```
header('Location: http://google.com');
unlink('test.txt');
```

В этом случае, вторая строка выполнится и файл test.txt будет удален. Если это не желательно, то естественно пишем так:

```
header('Location: http://google.com');
exit;
unlink('test.txt');
```