# Не срабатывает !isset($_SESSION)

Tags: php, сессия

Всем добрый вечер!

Есть такая проблема:
Человек может залогинится на сайт с помощью e-mail и пароля, если пароль и e-mail верен, то создается сессия:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```

Есть кнопка выйти, при нажатии на нее срабатывает следующая функция:

```
function getLogout(){

    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
        );
    }

    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    session_destroy();

}
```

Проверил через `echo $_SESSION['email']`, выдает пустоту после нажатия кнопки выход. Т.е сессия удаляется.

Но почему то редирект (код ниже), не срабатывает, т.е как будто сессия еще есть! Почему так?

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['email']) )  {
    header('http://site.ru');
}
```

Comment: Убедитесь что там действительно ничего нет:

if( !isset($_SESSION['email']) )  {
    header('http://site.ru');
}
else{
 echo "<pre>";
 var_dump($_SESSION);
}

Comment: Убедился. действительно ничего нет.

Comment: if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    header('site.ru');
    echo '123';

Причем выдает 123, но не редиректит

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/208354/%d0%92%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-exit-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0

Comment: Ну я поставил exit, но тогда просто белый экран, не редиректит все равно

Answer (score 1):

Правильно будет:

```
header("Location: http://site.ru");
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть подозрение что проблема не в сессиях, а в кодировке файлов. Возможно у вас где то затесался файл с BOM.

http://www.larshaendler.com/2015/01/20/remove-bom-with-notepad/

Comment: Проверил кодировку, файл без BOM

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем решил проблему

Так как сайт на wordpress, воспользовался их функцией

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    wp_redirect('http://site.ru');
    exit();
}
```