# isset($_SESSION['some_key']) возвращает true, хотя сессия пуста

Tags: php, авторизация, сессия

делаю авторизацию, проверка авторизирован ли юзер происходит через проверку существования $_SESSION['id'], для этого в главном классе приложения есть метод(пока только набросок)

```
static function Init(){
            if(isset($_SESSION['id'])):
                echo "non-auth";
            else:
                echo "auth";
            endif;
        }
```

этот метод я вызываю на одной из своих страниц и все время получаю auth, то есть юзер авторизован, хотя

```
var_dump($_SESSION['id']);
```

возвращает `undefined`
похожую проблему я нашел [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599184/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-isset-session), но у меня немного другая ситуация, у меня не wp, а самопис.
вот код тестовой страницы

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Core/autoload.php');
use Core\App;

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
// use App\App as c;
// use DB;
var_dump($_SESSION['id']);
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])):
  echo "non-auth";
else:
  echo "auth";
endif;
App::Init();


        ?>
```

а вот возврат
[image: var_dump($_SESSION['id']);]

Вот результат попытки вывода сессии через `print_r('$_SESSION');`
[image: вывод всей сессии]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А как вы запускаете сессию?

PHP же вываливает вам сообщение о том, что _SESSION не объявлена. Гуглите сессии.

Ну и все верно. Если не установлен ID написать non-auth, иначе auth. Вы тут перепутали местами логику.

Comment: Все, понял, я ошибся) перечитал еще раз мануал по isset))